# Django book chapter 6: unable to import Book model

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django going through the online book, and am presently stuck at [Chapter 6](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html). In the *Adding Your Models to the Admin Site* section the reader is required to create a file named `admin.py`, within the **books** app, with this content:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.books.models import Publisher, Author, Book

admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book)
```

This is supposed to make these models available for editing at the admin site, but what I get is the following:

> ImportError at /admin/ 
> No module named books.models

In the Python command line I get a similar error:

```
>>> from mysite.books.models import Book
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mysite.books.models
```

These are the contents of the `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']


class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have strictly followed the instructions in the book to this point, thus I should have an exact copy of the code used. The file structure was created automatically by Django:

```
books
  __init__.py
  admin.py
  models.py
  tests.py
  views.py
mysite
  templates
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  urls.py
  views.py
  wsgi.py
manage.py
```

What would be the correct way of importing the `models` file in the `admin` module?

Comment: care to share your file structure?

Comment: Please don't use the Django book. There's even a message on the front page warning you not to use it.

Comment: It had been useful so far, but I am all ears for an alternative.

Comment: It says not to use for "educational" purposes. I also have been using it, and also have not gotten stuck until here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty old book and some things are deprecated in current version of Django.

Try this import:

```
from books.models import Publisher, Author, Book
```

instead of:

```
from mysite.books.models import Publisher, Author, Book
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, it seems that `import` is actually interpreted at the same level of the `manage.py` file.